# Conexão HTTP com servidor não retorna os dados JSON

Tags: php, android, json, web-service, http

Olá, estou tentando pegar os dados de uma query via HTTP, mas está me retornando esse erro:

```
org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of
```

**O Código que tenho é esse:**

```
private class AsyncFetch extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    ProgressDialog pdLoading = new ProgressDialog(BuscaCAActivity.this);
    HttpURLConnection conn;
    URL url = null;
    String searchQuery;

    public AsyncFetch(String searchQuery){
        this.searchQuery=searchQuery;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        //this method will be running on UI thread
        pdLoading.setMessage("\tFazendo a busca...");
        pdLoading.setCancelable(false);
        pdLoading.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {

            // Enter URL address where your php file resides
            url = new URL(minha_url);

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return e.toString();
        }
        try {

            // Setup HttpURLConnection class to send and receive data from php and mysql
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

            // setDoInput and setDoOutput to true as we send and recieve data
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);

            // add parameter to our above url
            Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder().appendQueryParameter("codigo", searchQuery);
            String query = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();

            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(query);
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();
            conn.connect();

        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
            return e1.toString();
        }

        try {

            int response_code = conn.getResponseCode();

            // Check if successful connection made
            if (response_code == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                // Read data sent from server
                InputStream input = conn.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
                StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                String line;

                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    result.append(line);
                }

                // Pass data to onPostExecute method
                return (result.toString());

            } else {
                return("Connection error");
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return e.toString();
        } finally {
            conn.disconnect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        pdLoading.dismiss();
        if(result.equals("no result")) {
            Toast.makeText(BuscaCAActivity.this, getString(R.string.nenhum_resultado), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else{

            try {

                JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

                // Extract data from json and store into ArrayList as class objects
                for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    tvTeste.setText(json_data.getString("NRRegistro"));
                    tvTeste2.setText(json_data.getString("DataValidade"));
                    tvTeste3.setText(json_data.getString("Situacao"));
                    tvTeste4.setText(json_data.getString("NRProcesso"));
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }

}
```

**O PHP está assim:**

```
if(isset($_POST['codigo']))
{
      require_once('config.inc.php');
      $search_query=$_POST['codigo'];

      $sql = 'SELECT NRRegistro, DataValidade, Situacao, NRProcesso  FROM tab_cadastro WHERE NRRegistro = :search_query';

      $statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
      $statement->bindParam(':search_query', $search_query, PDO::PARAM_STR);
      $statement->execute();
      if($statement->rowCount())
      {
            $row_all = $statement->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            header('Content-type: application/json');
            echo json_encode($row_all);

      }  
      elseif(!$statement->rowCount())
      {
          echo "no result";
      }
}
```

Estou há horas tentando achar o erro e não consegui avançar.
O que está errado nesses códigos?

Comment: no doInBackground após todo o processo result tem valor?

Comment: @EdsonReis, na parte de conexão está tudo ok. O problema é na leitura do JSon no servidor. Já testei a instrução sql no phpmyadmin e está certa, então não sei onde está o erro.

Comment: leia o json dentro do doInBackground

Comment: Voce está dando "POST" sendo que você esta esperando um resultado pra montar o seu objeto... não seria "GET"?

Comment: Já tentei com Get também e nada. A codificação, tipo de campo no banco de dados e tabela influencia algo?

Comment: O erro que está acontecendo  diz que nenhum dado esta chegando para montar sua array, seu result é 0 quando monta no onPostExecute().

Comment: Vou postar uma resposta e você diz se funcionou.

Comment: Postei uma resposta, para voce passar para view terá que criar um adapter passando sua lista para a view

Answer (score 1):

Pode ser que o request não está retornando valor, ou o resultado do seu json não esta passando no método onPostExecute()

Tente separar responsabilidades é boas praticas de programação, fica mais fácil de interpretar código e consertar erros.

1. Crie uma classe que tem a responsabilidade de fazer o request da sua url e trazer seu json

**HttpHandlerHelper**

```
        public class HttpHandlerHelper {

    private static final String TAG = HttpHandlerHelper.class.getSimpleName();
    private static Context context;
    public HttpHandlerHelper(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public String Request(String reqUrl) {
        String response = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(reqUrl);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            // read the response

            if (200 <= conn.getResponseCode() && conn.getResponseCode() <= 299) {
                InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
                response = convertStreamToString(in);
                return response;
            } else {
                InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getErrorStream());
                response = convertStreamToString(in);
                return response;
            }

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "MalformedURLException: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (ProtocolException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "ProtocolException: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "IOException: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return response;
    }
}

public static  String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line).append('\n');
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

2. Crie o modelo de data

**ModelObjeto**

```
public class ModelObjeto {

public String registro;
public String data_validade;
public String situacao;
public String processo;

public ModelObjeto() {
}

public Atleta(String registro,
              String data_validade,
              String situacao,
              String processo

)
{
    this.registro = registro;
    this.data_validade = data_validade;
    this.situacao = situacao;
    this.processo = processo;



}

public String getRegistro() {
    return registro;
}

public void setRegistro(String registro) {
    this.registro = registro;
}

public String getDataValidade() {
    return data_validade;
}

public void setDataValidade(String data_validade) {
    this.data_validade = data_validade;
}

public String getSituacao() {
    return situacao;
}

public void setSituacao(String situacao) {
    this.situacao = situacao;
}

public String getProcesso() {
    return processo;
}

public void setProcesso(String processo) {
    this.processo = processo;
}
```

}

3. Passe a parte que monta seu json em objeto para o doInBackground().

   ```
   public static class AsyncFetch extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {


       @Override
       protected void onPreExecute() {
           super.onPreExecute();

           pdLoading.setMessage("\tFazendo a busca...");
           pdLoading.setCancelable(false);
           pdLoading.show();

       }

       @Override
       protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

           objetos = new ArrayList<>();

           HttpHandlerHelper handler = new HttpHandlerHelper();
           String json = handler.Request(minha_url);

           if(json != null && json.equals("no result")) {

               try {

                   JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(json);
                   for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {

                       JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                       ModelObjeto objeto = new ModelObjeto();

                       objeto.registro = json_data.getString("NRRegistro");
                       objeto.data_validade = json_data.getString("DataValidade");
                       objeto.situacao = json_data.getString("Situacao");
                       objeto.processo = json_data.getString("NRProcesso");

                       objetos.add(objeto);
                   }

               } catch (JSONException e) {

                   e.printStackTrace();
               }

           }


           return null;
       }

       @Override
       protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

           pdLoading.dismiss();

       }

   }
   ```

Comment: Desculpa a demora. De semana é corrido pra mim. Estou fazendo testes, assim que tiver algum resultado eu volto para postar. Desde já eu agradeço pela ajuda.

Comment: Voltei para agradecer novamente pela ajuda e informar que o problema apresentado neste post estava no arquivo php mesmo. Refiz o código de outra forma e resolveu o problema, tanto por GET quanto por POST. Em relação à sugestão do código acima, tentei utilizá-lo no meu caso mas tenho que fazer alguns ajustes. Creio que se fizer os ajustes necessários ele funcione bem também e de forma até mais correta. De qualquer forma eu agradeço pela atenção.